# Have Superscript or a complex html tag inside AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, html

How can I use some complex html tag inside the ampscript and then pass it to email body?
For example, I need below tag inside AMPScript on preheader.

```
<sup style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 0; vertical-align: 4px;">+</sup>
```

Thanks
Matin

Comment: "<sup style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 0; vertical-align: 4px;">+</sup>"

Comment: As I didn't put my html tag inside " " , it displays just + , but I mean the sup tag.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not that difficult.  Store the HTML in a variable, such as:

```
SET @testvar = "<bold>test</bold>"
```

You may need to escape some of the special characters using "\" if its very complicated.

Then in your email, have the following at the placed you want it displayed:

```
%%=TreatAsContent(@testvar)=%%
```

Hope this helps.  Have a look at [this](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#TreatAsContent) for the details on how that works.